# Does $x^{*}y$ mean the same thing as $\langle y,x \rangle$?

Tags: inner-products

I am getting confused over some notation.

Does $x^{*}y$ mean the same thing as $\langle y,x \rangle$?

My book says that $$x^{*}y=\sum_{i=1}^m \bar{x_i}y_i$$ 
I am wondering if that is equivalent to $$x^{*}y=\sum_{i=1}^m y_i\bar{x_i}=\langle y,x \rangle$$

I think it is becasue the $x_i$ and $y_i$ are just numbers, but just want to make sure.

Thank you.

Comment: That's right. Complex multiplication is commutative.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate it.